# complex user_roles many to many setup

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design

I am writing a backend surveys database. The database is the backend for multiple applications that are used for gathering survey type data. I have a schema that includes a table that designates the application and what questions belong to that application.

now I need to setup users and userroles...

each user may have access to 1 or more applications
each application has 1 or more users

each user may have 1 role in the application they have access to
each role may exist in 1 or more applications
each user may have different roles in each application.

app1 has 15 users 1 user is admin
app1 has 2 roles defined for user access

app2 has 30 users admin user from app1 has access but is regular user
     2 admin users in app2 exist in app1 as normal users
app2 has 4 roles defined for user access.

***WARNING FREE FORM THOUGHT PROCESS***

so I have

Application ->ApplicationUsers<-Users

maybe I only need one joining table then like this?

[image]

Would that be correct? Would it work in EF 4.0?

What would be the correct way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that this

> each user may have 1 role in the
>   application they have access to each
>   role may exist in 1 or more
>   applications each user may have
>   different roles in each application.

should be punctuated like this.

> Each user may have 1 role in the
>   application they have access to, each
>   role may exist in 1 or more
>   applications, each user may have
>   different roles in each application.

If that first clause means that each user *must* have one and no more than one role in each application they have access to, then your schema won't work.  The compound primary key {ApplicationId, UserID, RoleID} in ApplicationUserRoles allows multiple roles per user.

To limit the constraint "one row (and one role) per user per application", the primary key for ApplicationUserRoles should be just {ApplicationID, UserID}.

Also, if UserID is unique in the table Users, it should probably be the primary key, and you should probably drop the column "ID" from that table.

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be a few different ways to implement the relationships and the biggest factor to determine the best way is how you intend to consume the data. It can be done with four tables as you describe, I prefer singular, not plural for all tables – up to the individual but you should be consistent and make it Applications if the other tables are plural. Since relationship is defined by all three entities, that should be the structure of the table. However, a question to ask is the ordinality of these relationships? I think it is clear that an application can exist whether it has users or not as could probably be said of a user whether it is currently associated to an application. However, would a role exist if it wasn’t related to an application? Probably not as a role (even though it may share the same name) may not be exactly equivalent in every application.

Another option, maybe more clear (better?) logically, would be to have a Role (AppRole?) table with the Application FK in it and a UserAppRole table that relates users to it. This would allow you to define a Role relative to the application it applies to and relate a user to an application(s) through the appropriate role(s).

Application
AppRole
User
UserAppRole

Like I said, lots of ways to do it and many determining factors.

Comment: +1 to jdcook72 for two things: (a) Use singular table names.  This is better practice at all times but especially in EF since your model will want to pluralize navigation properties that are collections of related child entities, and (b) ROLE belongs to the APP, since admin in App A is not the same as admin in App B.  This is a straight-forward parent/child relationship not an intersection.  For what it's worth, what jdcook calls "UserAppRole" I would call ROLE_MEMBER.

Comment: Yes definately. I was in a mind set from the standards imposed of my current work environment where tables are named by their relation structure as well as the OP's description that UserAppRole was just how it first roled out of my head. Given my druthers, I would use RoleMember as it just makes sense semanticly and I think that is priority for a table name. While I must admin that it is kind of convenient to be able to gleen some structure from table names, that's whatn an ERD is really for.